# Null reference exception using HttpClient with async/await in MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpclient, async-await

I am using HttpClient to call a REST API. HttpClient.GetAsync method works fine if I call it from a test project. But calling HttpClient.GetAsync() from an MVC 4 application throws an unhandled object reference not set exception with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext) 
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__1(Object s) 
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() 
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() 
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I am running .NET Framework 4.5. Any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Is your Controller Action also async?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Yes, My Controller action is async. I tried making the controller actions synchronous, but then HttpClient.GetAsync() never returns.

Comment: Can you post the code block which contains the whole structure invoking `HttpClient.GetAsync()`?